# Impossible drop table during s:up after disable MSI

Tags: magento2, msi

I have disable MSI M 2.4.0 and now I try run upgrade but I get:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1829 Cannot drop column 'source_code': needed in a foreign key constraint 'INVENTORY_SOURCE_ITEM_SOURCE_CODE_INVENTORY_SOURCE_SOURCE_CODE' of table ``.`inventory_source_item`, query was: ALTER TABLE `inventory_source` DROP COLUMN `source_code`, DROP COLUMN `name`, DROP COLUMN `enabled`, DROP COLUMN `description`, DROP COLUMN `latitude`, DROP COLUMN `longitude`, DROP COLUMN `country_id`, DROP COLUMN `region_id`, DROP COLUMN `region`, DROP COLUMN `city`, DROP COLUMN `street`, DROP COLUMN `postcode`, DROP COLUMN `contact_name`, DROP COLUMN `email`, DROP COLUMN `phone`, DROP COLUMN `fax`, DROP COLUMN `use_default_carrier_config`, DROP PRIMARY KEY
```

Comment: what did you run for the disabling of MSI?

Comment: https://magecomp.com/blog/how-to-disable-msi-in-magento-2/

Comment: @DianaBotean do you have any solution ?

Answer (score 10):

SOLVED.

If someone is looking for a solution, with this instruction not all modules have been disabled, so it returns an error when s: up Then run:

```
php bin/magento module:status | grep Magento_Inventory | grep -v List | grep -v None | grep -v -e '^$' | xargs php bin/magento module:disable
php bin/magento s:upgrade
php bin/magento s:s:deploy -f
php bin/magento c:flush
php bin/magento i:reindex
```

Comment: This isn't a solution if you want to use the modules, but +1 for the 1 liner